# Lateral movement on rear cassette

Tags: wheels, cassette, hub, drivetrain

My cassette (SRAM XG-1175) moves axially about 5 to 8mm (in line with the axle, not up and down) on my hub (whatever is standard on a 2016 Enduro Elite)

But the part of the hub the cassette mounts to also moves with the cassette.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Sounds like the freehub body is loose. Depending on what type of hub and bearings, either the freehub body screw is loose or bearings are shot. Worn bearings isn't a far fetch on a mountain bike if you're a rough rider.

Comment: A picture of the cassette perpendicular to the axle might be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'part of the hub the cassette mounts to' is the *freehub body*. That is evidently loose, or damaged.

5-8mm is a lot of movement. Don't ride the bike until you have fixed the problem. You would likely damage the freehub mechanism, and may suffer a jammed chain which could be dangerous.

Each manufacturers freehub disassembles in a different way. [This Park Tool article](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/freehub-service) will give you and idea of the types. First step is to get your cassette off and find out what type of hub you have, then find specific instructions for disassembling and inspecting it.